# Terminology | Codomain with only the outputs of the function over a given domain

Tags: set-theory, terminology

Given the function $f: A \to B$ and $C = \{ f(a) \mid a \in A \}$, by definition $C \subseteq B$, but $C$ may or may not be equal to B. If we want to specify that the codomain of f is as small as possible - ie, exactly equal to $C$ and not a superset of it - then is there a standardized term to describe such a codomain and/or function?

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function

Comment: @peabrainiac Thanks!